# Overflow-x:auto stops working when it's container has dispay:block property

Tags: css, html-table, flexbox, overflow, scrollable

I have two tables nested in a parent table, both in the same table row.

I want the second table to be scrollable and the first to be fixed.

Without `display: block`, the second table overlaps the first, but with `display: block`, it is no longer scrollable.

When table headings/content are smaller, there are no issues at all.

Here is my code:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  *border-collapse: expression('separate', cellSpacing='10px');
}

.test {}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed">
  <tr>
    <td>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Jogger_123</th>
          <th>Sprinter_123</th>
          <th>Swimmer_321</th>
          <th>Dancer_321</th>
          <th>Fisher_567</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

    <td>

      <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table class='test'>
          <tr>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the table elements to `width: 100%`.

But the table cells overflow the size of the container.

So the first `td`, which is set to `overflow: visible` by default, can be seen overlapping the second `td` and the container.

The second `td` fits nicely in the container because it has `overflow-x: auto`.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

#table1 {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

#table2 {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed; border: 2px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="table1">
        <tr>
          <th>Jogger_123</th>
          <th>Sprinter_123</th>
          <th>Swimmer_321</th>
          <th>Dancer_321</th>
          <th>Fisher_567</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

    <td>

      <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table class='test' id="table2">
          <tr>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The question you need to ask yourself is how you want to handle the overflow of the first `td`. Also `overflow-x`?

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

#table1 { border: 2px dashed red;  }
#table2 { border: 2px dashed blue; }
```

```html
<table style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed; border: 2px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <td style="overflow: auto">
      <table id="table1">
        <tr>
          <th>Jogger_123</th>
          <th>Sprinter_123</th>
          <th>Swimmer_321</th>
          <th>Dancer_321</th>
          <th>Fisher_567</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
          <td><input type='text'></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

    <td>

      <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table class='test' id="table2">
          <tr>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you made me think about it differently & I fixed the issue. I removed table width 100% and instead of overflow-x:auto, I did overflow-x:scroll forcing the browser to put in the scrollbar, then I gave it a width so the scrollbar would actually show up.